# Таймер,должен через время положить файл на БД

Tags: php

Мне нужен таймер, а я хз как его делать именно, чтоб в конкретное время он сохранял информацию в файлю
Мне главное, чтобы он в конкретный период времени, например 12:00:00 смог взять данные из базы и положить их в файлик, где-нибудь на хостинге

Answer (score 2):

[Крон](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) в помощь, создаешь файл с подключеним к базе, достаешь инфу и кладешь куда нужно (файл который нужен в итоге!), а файл которы все этот делает ставишь на запуск в крон